# how can i install rviz in JADE ROS

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i came across the need for visualization in ROS which requires rviz, when i went to the http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide it gave me some code to install the RVIZ code, i used
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-visualization

but it gave an error

```
E: unable to locate package ros-fuerte-visualization
```

i dont know which of the given codes should i run to install it in JADE as the given code is for groovy, hydro and indigo can anyone help plz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223836/how-can-i-install-rviz-in-jade-ros/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The page you link is pretty clear about it:

> From groovy on:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rviz
> ```

```
# or
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz
# or
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rviz
```

You're installing for Jade, so I suggest:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rviz
```

similar to all the other Jade packages that I assume you've already installed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-01-17**:
thank you!